# Unable to position y axis properly and missing max number on y-axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to display a grouped bar graph.

Two problems:

1. y axis is displaying only till 90, i want it to be till 100.
2. y axis is going below x axis and also x axis is not positioned properly.

SVG width, height are with margins, whereas chart display area are without margins.

In `yScale`, `height` should represent chart area i.e without margins.

so, placing `y` axis from `height` i.e chart area height, I have expected `y` axis to begin from x axis line level to upwards. but it's not happening.

```js
      var data = [
        {
          model_name: "model_1",
          field1: 19,
          field2: 83,
        },
        {
          model_name: "model_2",
          field1: 67,
          field2: 93,
        },
        {
          model_name: "model_3",
          field1: 10,
          field2: 56,
        },
      ];

      var margin = { top: 30, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 50 },
        // chart display area width, height 
        width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right, 
        height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
        barPadding = 0.2,
        axisTicks = { outerSize: 0 };

      var svg = d3
        .select("body")
        .append("svg")
        // svg area width, height with margins added.
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

      var xScale0 = d3
        .scaleBand()
        .range([0, width])
        .padding(barPadding);
      var xScale1 = d3.scaleBand();
      var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]); 

      xScale0.domain(data.map((d) => d.model_name));
      xScale1.domain(["field1", "field2"]).range([0, xScale0.bandwidth()]);

      yScale.domain([
        0,
        d3.max(data, (d) => (d.field1 > d.field2 ? d.field1 : d.field2)),
      ]);

      var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale0).tickSizeOuter(axisTicks.outerSize);
      var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale).tickSize(0);

      svg
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr(
          "transform",
          `translate(0,${height - margin.top - margin.bottom})`
        )
        .call(xAxis);

      svg
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)
        .call((g) => g.select(".domain").remove());

      var model_name = svg
        .selectAll(".model_name")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "model_name")
        .attr("transform", (d) => `translate(${xScale0(d.model_name)},0)`);

      /* Add field1 bars */
      model_name
        .selectAll(".bar.field1")
        .data((d) => [d])
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("class", "bar field1")
        .style("fill", "skyblue")
        .attr("x", () => xScale1("field1"))
        .attr("y", (d) => yScale(d.field1))
        .attr("width", xScale1.bandwidth())
        .attr("height", (d) => {
          return height - yScale(d.field1);
        });

      /* Add field2 bars */
      model_name
        .selectAll(".bar.field2")
        .data((d) => [d])
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("class", "bar field2")
        .style("fill", "orange")
        .attr("x", () => xScale1("field2"))
        .attr("y", (d) => yScale(d.field2))
        .attr("width", xScale1.bandwidth())
        .attr("height", (d) => {
          return height - yScale(d.field2);
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many issues related to the margin convention implementation, check this [tutorial](https://observablehq.com/@d3/margin-convention) on observable to have clear understanding of the [margin convention](https://observablehq.com/@d3/margin-convention)

I think here is what you have do in your chart to make it working:

```js
var data = [
  {
    model_name: "model_1",
    field1: 19,
    field2: 83,
  },
  {
    model_name: "model_2",
    field1: 67,
    field2: 93,
  },
  {
    model_name: "model_3",
    field1: 10,
    field2: 56,
  },
];

var margin = { top: 30, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 50 },
  // chart display area width, height
  width = 500, 
  height = 300,
  barPadding = 0.2,
  axisTicks = { outerSize: 0 };

var svg = d3
  .select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height]);

var xScale0 = d3
  .scaleBand()
  
  .range([margin.left, width - margin.right])
  .padding(barPadding);
var xScale1 = d3.scaleBand();
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([height - margin.top - margin.bottom, margin.top]); 

xScale0.domain(data.map((d) => d.model_name));
xScale1.domain(["field1", "field2"]).range([0, xScale0.bandwidth()]);

yScale.domain([
  0,
  100,
]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale0).tickSizeOuter(axisTicks.outerSize);
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale).tickSize(0);

svg
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr(
    "transform",
    `translate(0,${height - margin.bottom - margin.top})`
  )
  .call(xAxis);

svg
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .attr(
    "transform",
    `translate(${margin.left},0)`
  )
  .call(yAxis)
  .call((g) => g.select(".domain").remove())
  

var model_name = svg
  .selectAll(".model_name")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "model_name")
  .attr("transform", (d) => `translate(${xScale0(d.model_name)},0)`);

/* Add field1 bars */
model_name
  .selectAll(".bar.field1")
  .data((d) => [d])
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar field1")
  .style("fill", "skyblue")
  .attr("x", () => xScale1("field1"))
  .attr("y", (d) => yScale(d.field1))
  .attr("width", xScale1.bandwidth())
  .attr("height", (d) => {
    return ( height - margin.bottom - margin.top ) - yScale(d.field1);
  });

/* Add field2 bars */
model_name
  .selectAll(".bar.field2")
  .data((d) => [d])
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar field2")
  .style("fill", "orange")
  .attr("x", () => xScale1("field2"))
  .attr("y", (d) => yScale(d.field2))
  .attr("width", xScale1.bandwidth())
  .attr("height", (d) => {
    return (height - margin.bottom - margin.top) - yScale(d.field2);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: while giving yScale range, As we have already removed margin.top, margin.bottom, ie   **height = 300 - margin.bottom - margin.top**,
 if I directly give,  var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([**height**, margin.top]);  -- why this is not working? only if I give,  var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([height - margin.top - margin.bottom, margin.top]);  it is placing y-axis properly.

Comment: not sure I got your question, can you clarify more what is the issue.

Comment: ok, sure. so, we defined height = 300 - margin.bottom - margin.top implies now the height is a vertical length without any margins ie minus top and bottom margin.   so, now in order to position y axis at correct bottom point position ie just to start beside x-axis, this height if we give in  yScale range(**height**, margin.top) should start at the correct  bottom point. so, my point is since we are already removing top, bottom margins, so, why can't we use 'height' as is now, instead again at yscale range we are removing -margin.top-margin.bottom. then only y-axis is positioned correctly. why?

Comment: I updated my answer, sorry for having the miss-leading width/height value, the trick here is that the width and height will always be fit since I'm using view box, and you have to subtract the margins from the y/x scales so that they fit in the [viewbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox) of the svg.